# Find the 3rd point in a right triangle

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems

I've got this question in my worksheet:

**BAC** is a right triangle in **A**, given **B**(3,-1) , **C**(1,3)

If length of **AB** = length of **AC**, find the coordinates of point **A**.

I tried everything possible to do, I've even graphed it on a paper as a right triangle, and according to my graph, length **AC** isn't equal to length of **AB**.

Please help.

Comment: Hint:  what is the locus of points equidistant from $B$ and $C$?  What is the locus of points $P$ such that $\Delta BPY$ has a right angle at $P$?

Comment: uhm, if I got your question properly, the line that connects between A and line BC is which perpendicular on BC?

Comment: Well, there is no $A$ in my question.  But, yes, the locus of points equidistant from $B$ and $C$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment $BC$.  Now, what is the locus of points $P$ such that $\Delta BPC$ is a right triangle at $P$?  (Hint:  use the Theorem of Thales).

Comment: BC? Although I solved it, thanks. Still interested in your method though. (Sorry if I misunderstand something, I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: I'm describing the "constructive" solution...the way it would be done with compass and straightedge.  Easy to enough to find the coordinates this way as well:  The [Theorem of Thales] tells us that the locus of points $P$ such that $\Delta BPC$ is a right triangle at $P$ is the circle with diameter $BC$ (By $BC$ I mean the line segment with endpoints $B$ and $C$).  Therefore to solve your problem you need to find the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ with that circle.

Comment: So I'll have 2 equations:

(x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 5
x = 2y

then I get two solutions: (0,0) and (4,2)

Interesting, now I have 2 methods in hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\vec{AB}=(3-x;-1-y)$$ and $$\vec{AC}=(1-x;3-y)$$ and now calculate the dot-product

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't been taught the dot product yet. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Form equation of line perpendicular the line segment joining $B$ and $C$ and passing through midpoint of $BC$ i.e. $(2,1)$.It will be $2y-x=0$

(Here you get locus of points equidistant from $B$ and $C$)

**Step 2.** Take a parametric point $A$ on that line. i.e. $(2t,t)$

**Step 3.** Apply condition for $\text{BA} \bot \text{AC}$ :$$m_{AB} \cdot m_{AC} = -1 ~;~~~~~~~~\text{( $m$ denotes slope)} $$

You will get two points. On solving for $t$ :
$$t = 0 , 2 \implies A(0,0) ~\text{or} ~A(4,2) $$

Comment: Alright, I formed the equation of the line, but can you elaborate step 2 more please?

Comment: @Just_Cause Assume $y=t$ , then satisfying on the equation of line $2y-x=0$, you'll get $x=2t $.Parametric means reducing into single variable.

Comment: Thanks, I got you. Both points actually can be point A